# Compiling Bitcoin on Visual C++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, bitcoin, bitcoind

I'm trying to compile bitcoin-0.8.6 on Windows using Visual C++ 2010. What I did until now was to create an empty project, added the Bitcoin source files to it, setuped boost/openssl. I'm getting the following syntax error in addrman.h file:

> addrman.h(380): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'

The line where the error occurs is related to the IMPLEMENT_SERIALIZE macro:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.8.6/src/addrman.h#L380

IMPLEMENT_SERIALIZE macro is defined in serialize.h:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.8.6/src/serialize.h#L55

Since Bitcoin was made for GCC/Mingw, I guess there is an incompatibility issue with the way the macros are defined (or I'm wrong?).

Comment: Preprocess the file (compile with /P) and see what comes out.  This will likely make the syntax issue easier to find.

Comment: Thanks James, it will be helpful. The only problem is that the result of the preprocess related to the macro is too large and doesn't contain new line characters - they've been overwritten by space characters. Because of this I couldn't be able to format it for analysing.

Answer (score 0):

2017 update:
Compilation via the new "Windows Subsystem for Linux" feature in 10 (Ubuntu bash prompt)
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-windows.md